# Using JSON response from Flask Restful with Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, flask-restful

I started learning APIs with flask restful and angular 6, I've made some progress but I'm stuck trying to get an API json response with angular and extract the message it has.

I managed to make it work with custom exceptions when there is an error, so if the api finds and error it will raise an exception and flask will respond with something like:

```
{
    'message': "An account with this email already exists.",
    'status': 409,
}
```

And that works, I managed to send a notification with that message to the user in angular with this:

```
this.userService.register(this.registerForm.value)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
            (data) => {
                //THIS DOESN'T
                this.notificationService.success(environment.notifications.successTitle, data);
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            },
            (err) => {
                // THIS WORKS!
                this.notificationService.error(environment.notifications.errorTitle, err);
                this.showSpinner = false;
            });
```

When the APIs sends an error as I showed the json above, it works, if I do

```
console.log(err);
```

it prints just the message, even though the response body contains that whole json, the data on the other hand (when there is no error), if I do

```
console.log(data);
```

it prints the entire json.

I know that if I do something like data['message'] it will work, but I want to know why when there is an error, the err variable only contains the message, and data contains the whole json.

Both responses from the API have the same headers, same body the only thing that changes is the message and the statu in the json. But when I console.log the err variable it only shows the message, data on the other hand shows the entire json.

I don't even know if this whole question is an issue or if it is intended to work like this, in that case should I use data['message']? What if data doesn't have a message for some reason?

I tried returning from the APIs like this:

```
return jsonify({"message": "Account created successfully."}), 201
return {"message": "Account created successfully."}, 201
return jsonify({"message": "Account created successfully.", "status": 201})
```

I've also tried to create a custom Response (from flask) instance but with no success.
And if I use jsonify it gives me the "is not JSON serializable" error.

I thought about making every response an exception but that just doesn't make sense.

Comment: if data doesn't have a message,it would return `None`